# Integration of cos (0x)

Tags: numerical-integration

`Integrate cos(mx)` from $x=0$ to $x=2pi$.

Then **put $m=0$.** We get an indefinite form ${0/0}$.

But answer is $2pi$.

Why such paradox arises?

Comment: This looks more like a question for mathematica.stackexchange.com? Do you have a specific *Mathematica* angle? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: The answer in all cases is [`2 Pi Sinc[2 Pi m]`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) -- where's the paradox?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
int = Integrate[Cos[m*x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

> Sin[2 m π]/m

```
Limit[int, {m -> 0}]
```

> {2 π}